# How can I format google sheets so I can export my data properly?

Tags: python, sql, google-sheets

I plan to make an educational web game. I have thousands of trivia questions I need to write down in a way that can be easily transferred out and automatically organized based on their column, at a later date.

I was suggested to use google sheets so I can later export as a .csv, and that should be easy to work with for a developer. When i exported a .csv and opened it in Panda python the a column was cut off and 1 column was used as a 'header', not just a normal entry https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkmU2.jpg. This obviously wont work and seems to be an issue.

Should I just leave the first row and column empty and work around the issue? I don't want to write thousands of sets only to find out I did this the wrong way. Can anyone give any insight into whether this is my best option and how I should best format it?

I have to write Questions(1), Answers(4), Explanations(1) per entry

I hope this makes sense, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing this and have no issue at all using the exported CSV from Google Sheets, using the same data as in your example.

In my opinion, whatever software you're using in your second screenshot is your issue, it seems like its removing numbers from the first row because that should be your header row. Check around in your software for options like, "First column contains headers" or "Use row 1 as Header" and make sure these aren't being used.

Comment: If you're going to use Python to manipulate the data, read the csv into pandas, then put the contents into an array and print the array to see if it looks like your expectation then go from there.